# Step Debugger for PHP other than Zend Debugger

Tags: php, debugging

I just wanted to see if anyone is aware of any other debuggers capable of stepping through code.

I am aware of xdebug and use it as well as Zend Debugger and other debugging scripts (i've written my own widgets for this already).

However I am looking for a good replacement for step debugging - I've searched and searched but have yet to find anything.  Is there anything else out there that can handle this? Surely Zend Debugger isn't our only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [php_dbg](http://www.php-debugger.com/dbg/installation.php) for my PHP step-debugging (comes with PhpED).

Comment: Awesome - I had heard of PhpED but wasn't aware of this.  I'm going to give this a go and see if it fits the bill. Thanks!