# What is a good MVC strategy for generating and debugging reports?

Tags: php, debugging, multidimensional-array, reporting, nested-loops

I'm looking to collect tips, blogs, and other best practices on debugging the generation of report data.

I'm not looking for reporting classes, [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747103/something-like-crystal-reports-for-php) [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862607/report-generation-in-php-formats-required-pdf-xls-doc-csv) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920889/open-source-php-reporting-tool) exist here about this already.  These won't help in getting the data from the data layer and readying it for printing (unless there's a library that has some relevant 'pre-flight' functions).

I'm working in a MVC framework (CodeIgniter, but that shouldn't matter), and so one debugging conundrum is the revealing of important variables at each point in the loops. Log it? Dump to screen?

I think using a [step-wise PHP debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516385/step-debugger-for-php-other-than-zend-debugger) would make the process easier, but I'm interested in pulling out better strategies for report generation and debugging in general.

I think that verbal description of any tips / etc would also be valuable to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug / FirePHP : http://www.firephp.org/

It supports all kinds of logging to the browser, including tables and stack traces.

If you don't want to implement it by hand, the Zend_Framework Wildfire log writer can be used with CodeIgniter:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.writers.html#zend.log.writers.firebug